# Getting information from multiple folders at the same time

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am implementing code in Google Colaboratory where I'm trying to reach 2 types of files (see picture) to use trec_eval.

[image: Class (folder) structure and the files I want to use]

I so far have the following code:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import os

def get_p(qrels_files, results_files):
  list_p = []
  for folder in (qrels_files, results_files):
    p = os.popen(f"./trec_eval P.20 {qrels_files} {results_files}").read()
    list_p.append(p)
  return list_p

path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/data/classes"
qrels_files = Path(path).glob("*/qrel*_N.txt")
results_files = Path(path).glob("*/results*_N.txt")
get_p(qrels_files, results_files)
```

I'm trying to get the "qrel(insert number)_N" and the "results(insert number)_N" files from all the directories I have and I'm implementing the evaluation measure in trec_eval inside the `for` loop so that, that way, the measure can be executed for every class (class=folder where the qrels and results files are). After the measures are done, they are stored in the lists assigned to every measure so that, after, I would use said lists in a Pandas DataFrame.

However, when I execute the code, this happens:

```py
['', '']
```

The issue is related to the way I access the files and insert them in `trec_eval`. Any tips to what might be exactly?